# How to find my password for iCloud

Tags: icloud, apple-id

My Apple computer is about 6 years old.  The original and current apple password is 5 letters, all lower case, plus one digit.  It opens my computer and I consider it my apple password.  Unfortunately, when on my iPhone or iPad, and I am asked for my "apple password" it does not and cannot work (it doesn't fit password requirements). If I try to create a new password, for my iPhone and iPad, I cannot make it happen, no matter what instructions I have followed in the support information. My husband who has all the Apple gadgets and computer, has tried but is unable to assist me.

Comment: The password to enter your account on the computer is nothing to do with the Apple password it is for your user name on the computer alone. For iPad/iPhone  there are two user ids one for iCloud and one for the App Store you have to register for both of this - have you ever done this?

Answer (score 3):

If you have ever signed up for an Apple ID, which is the user name you use for everything at Apple including iCloud, you can recover/reset your password at this page:

https://iforgot.apple.com

This is **not** the same as the password you used to lock down a user account on a computer running OSX.